# Writing data to memory in C++

Tags: c++

I want to write a a mix of int, char, real in void *data.
I am using a file pointer to run through the data block.
Now my question is that since the data type is void, I have to typecast it to int while writing integer and char for writing string. 
While typecasting I used the following sample code:

```
*((int *)data+0) = 14;      //writing int
*((int *)data+4) = 5;       //writing int, left a space of 4 bytes for int
*((char *)data+8) = 'a';    //writing char
*((char *)data+9) = 'f';    //writing char
```

But then while reading the values back it didnt give the correct value.

```
cout<<*((int *)data+0);
cout<<*((int *)data+3);
cout<<*((char *)data+8);
```

Is the way my code is written correct? I am doubtful about it as data is void.

Comment: If you really want to use code like this, make sure that you have turned of strict aliasing in the compiler. Because you are breaking the strict aliasing rule.

Comment: A better approach would be to use a library such as [Boost.Serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) for writing/reading binary data.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be, if the data pointer were a character class (like char or uint8_t) then it doesn't break the aliasing rules so long as the _members_ don't overlap.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y Please read the question. Data is `void*`.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be, I know, that's why I say _were_ to indicate an option that is easier than turning off aliasing rules.

Answer (score 2):

```
*((int *)data+4) = 5; // writing 4th int
cout<<*((int *)data+3); // but reading third one
```

And just in case, ((int *)data+4) points to 4th integer (that is, 16th byte given int size = 4), not to 4th byte. That is, you code overwrites bytes 0-3, then 16-19, then 8th, then 9th. What you probably meant is: `*(int *)( (char*)data + X )`

Answer (score 1):

**Edited** to correct mistake pointed out by MSalters

Apart from the typo that others have mentioned (`data+3` instead of `data+4`), you also need to change e.g.

```
*((int *)data+4)
```

to

```
*((int *)data+1)
```

because adding `4` to an `int *` doesn't add `4` to the address, it adds `4 * sizeof (int)`.

If you need to write to an offset that is not a multiple of `sizeof(int)` (say, 7), you need:

```
*(int *)((char *)data+7)
```

For this reason, it might be better to make `data` a `char *` to start with, so you can just say

```
*(int *)(data+7)
```

Comment: -1, adding `4` to a `void*` doesn't work either. (since `sizeof(void)` is illegal). Correct: `*(static_cast<int *>(data)+1)`

Comment: @MSalters: Yes, you're right. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You're writing the second one with:

```
*((int *)data+4) = 5;    // offset = 4
```

and reading it back with:

```
cout<<*((int *)data+3);  // offset = 3
```

In addition, the `(int*)` cast is binding to `data`, not `data+4` so that your `4` is scaled up by the size of an `int`.

If you really want to do this (and a `struct` is not a possibility due to variances in the data formats), you should cast `data` to a `char*`, then add the number of bytes to get the `char` offset, then cast *that* to your desired type.

That would be something like:

```
*((int*)((char*)(data + 0)) = 14;    //writing int
*((int*)((char*)(data + 4)) = 5;     //writing int
*((char*)data + 8) = 'a';            //writing char
*((char*)data + 9) = 'f';            //writing char
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a class or a struct.

Here, pointer arithmetics is misleading you. When you add `4` to an `int *` you are adding actually four times `sizeof int`.

Answer (score 0):

If your data has a constant layout, why don't you just use a `struct` such as

```
struct MemoryLayout {
    int _first;
    int _second;
    char _c1;
    char _c2;
};
```

?

Answer (score 0):

```
int Data;
//char Data;
//float Data;

FILE *File = fopen("File.txt","wb");
fwrite((char *)&Data,sizeof(Data),1,File);
fclose(File);

File = fopen("File.txt","rb");
fread((char *)&Data,sizeof(Data),1,File);
fclose(File);
```

...

```
int DataInt1 = 200;
char DataChar1 = 'N';

FILE *File = fopen("File.txt","wb");
fwrite((char *)&DataInt1,sizeof(DataInt1),1,File);
fwrite((char *)&DataChar1,sizeof(DataChar1),1,File);
fclose(File);

int DataInt2 = 0;
char DataChar2 = 0;

File = fopen("File.txt","rb");
fread((char *)&DataInt2,sizeof(DataInt2),1,File);
fread((char *)&DataChar2,sizeof(DataChar2),1,File);
fclose(File);

printf("%d %d!\n",DataInt2,DataChar2);
```