# Write data to memory in c++

Tags: c++

I had posted a question on this but I thought to use memcmp() function instead.
[Writing data to memory in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790751/writing-data-to-memory-in-c/7790785#comment9505045_7790785)

```
int x = 1;
int fileptr = 0;
void *data = malloc(4096);
memcpy((int *)data+fileptr, &x, sizeof(int));
```

Then I read the values back

```
int y;
fileptr = 0;
memcpy(&y, (int *)data+fileptr, sizeof(int));
cout<<y;
```

In this way, I get a different output for variable y (some long integer values). Please need immediate help.

Comment: Welcome to stack Overflow! What, precisely, is your question?

Comment: I don't see any use of `memcmp` here. If you explain *what problem led you to this solution*, I'm sure people can help you find much better solutions that don't involve micro-managing pointers and running into undefined behaviours at every turn.

Comment: You didn't initialize `data`.  You are writing to a random memory address.

Comment: I suspect you don't understand what you're doing, or how pointers work.

Answer (score 4):

You declare a pointer `data` but never initialize it. So the behavior is undefined. You have to point `data` somewhere, i.e. allocate memory. See [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/).

Comment: @Akshay: In that case, you're doing something terribly wrong. See your program again and  then compile and run it again!

Comment: Is there any problem in typecasting of data?
As characters are showing up properly but not integers.
Since int is 4 bytes i thought sumthing might be wrong there

Comment: Hey thanks a lot... I am going so deep in pointers for the first time.
I just uncommented unwanted part and ran it again. It ran fine.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there's some code you're leaving out, `data` is never initialized, and hence points to some random location. Since your application isn't crashing entirely, you're probably getting (somewhat) lucky and ending up with `data` pointing into a location on the stack which is written to by other code; hence the change in value.

Allocate some memory for `data` before you write to it and this won't happen.

Answer (score 0):

You havent allocated any storage for data - so when you copy the int data there you are causing no end of problems by corrupting the stack.

You might want to do something like

```
int x = 1;
void *data=new int();
memcpy(data, &x, sizeof(x)); // never use the type use the var - more resilient to change
```

Comment: Here the problem is that data type is a void and I have to store a mix of int, char, reals.
So I cant use data = new int();

Answer (score 0):

That actually invokes undefined behaviour, as you have not allocated memory for `data`. Where should it store the bit-patterns of `x` then?

If you have allocated memory (using `malloc`), and still get wrong output, then in that case, you are doing something terribly wrong. See your program again and then compile and run it again. Because the output cannot be anything other than `1`. See this:

- http://www.ideone.com/SBoHk

Compare your program with mine (in the above link) word by word, and see if there is anything you are missing.

Comment: @Akshay: See I told you, there is something you are doing wrong. Now see what you are doing in the so-called unwanted code which affects the output.